# Inscribed kissing circles in an isosceles trapezoid

Tags: circles, geometry

5 equal circles in an isosceles trapezoid. Radius of circle is 4. Find black colored area.
[image: Trapezoid with circles]

I don't have any ideas, could you give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?  Evaluate the black area?  Dimensions of the trapezoid?

Comment: @Ross find area, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area (that one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearly the area of the colored region is 3 times the area of one of the curved triangles.

Draw a regular hexagon around one of the circles, in such a way that all of its sides are tangent to the circle (i.e., the circle is inscribed in the hexagon). There are 6 regions of the hexagon that are not contained in the circle, one at each vertex of the hexagon:
[image]

Note that any one of the curved triangles in your picture consists of 3 of these hexagon corners.

Let $A$ be the area of a hexagon with inradius 4. Let $B$ be the area of a circle with radius 4. The total area of 6 hexagon corner regions is $A-B$. The region we want to find is made of 3 curved triangles, each of which is made of 3 hexagon corners, for a total of 9 hexagon corners. Thus, the area of the colored region is $\frac{3}{2}(A-B)$.

Comment: +1, Note to OP: in particular, the fact that it was a trapezoid didn't matter at all.

Comment: OMG thanks, I would never think of it myself

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to figure out the area of a hexagon and easier to look it up, but I don't know it off the top of my head and I think the problem can be done without it. The area formulas for trapezoids and circles would be enough considering this figure:
[image]

Comment: In reference to stuart's drawing: Note that the height of the (inner) trapezoid, the top of it and the two non parallel sides are all equal to the diameter of the a circle (2r), and the longest side is two times the diameter of a circle. The area comprised of sectors of circles inside the smaller trapezoid total 3/2 time the area of one circle: top and bottom left sectors are supplementary (total 1/2 circle), same with top and bottom circles, and 1/2 of the middle bottom circle is contained in the trapezoid.  Area trapezpoid - 3/2(area circle) = desired area.

Comment: The height of the inner trapezoid isn't the diameter of the circles, but it's still easy to figure out.

Comment: Ahhh...dah...you're right about the height; it's still easy to figure out given all the other info; one could construct a right triangle by drawing the segment extending from the center of upper left circle, intersecting lower side perpendicularly: that gives hypotenuse = 2d, short leg = 1/2 d...the rest is quite obvious...This was precisely the approach I took when solving the problem...by the time I had drawn the picture, you had already posted yours! :D

Answer (score 3):

The hexagonal solution is lovely, and the trapezoid picture is pretty nice.  But there are cruder ways that perhaps require less insight.

Let's find the area of **one** of the three black chunks.  To do this, join the centers of the circles it fits between.  We get an equilateral triangle of side $8$.
From the area of this, you must subtract three $60^\circ$ sectors, which together have half the area of a circle of radius $4$, that is, $8\pi$.

With basic trigonometry, or otherwise, one finds that an equilateral triangle of side $a$ has area $a^2\sqrt{3}/4$.  Here $a=8$, so the area is $16\sqrt{3}$.  Thus one little black chunk has area $16\sqrt{3}-8\pi$, and all three have combined area
$$48\sqrt{3}-24\pi.$$